# Code-Deploy is seccessful but then autoscale terminates all instances

Tags: aws-code-deploy

A new issue has just started yesterday from months of working correctly with nothing being changed to jenkins or aws settings

I have 5 Machines in an autoscale group with git push triggering jenkins to build and then use the jenkins aws codedeploy module to push up to code-deploy. i have the deployment set to OneAtATime.

The issue starts when the 5 are successful and the deployment is marked as successful. I get a new deployment being triggered with:

```
Initiated by              autoScaling
Deployment Config         CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce
Minimum Healthy Hosts     0 of 1 instances
```

For 5 individual deployments and all 5 instances are shutting down and terminated. I managed to grab one during the net deployment and checked everything and nothing looks wrong. no errors. Cdedeploy daemon is running etc. After the 5 individual deployments are successful the servers are running fine.

What could be causing this all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

The new deployment that has autoScaling as creator is caused by an instance scale up event in the ASG. When a deployment group is created with ASG, and has been successfully deployed, every time an instance is scaled up, a deployment will be triggered to sync the new instance with most recent software with other running instances. But CodeDeploy has no idea why the instance in ASG got terminated, it could be caused by health check of the ASG etc.

Thanks,
Binbin